# SAXParseException - The entity "szlig" was referenced, but not declare. Error by XML validation?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xerces

please helm me.

I have XML string that I validating. And sometimes, the document does not pass validation. Because there is a word "Weiß". How to fix this and other similar errors? I understand that swears on the letter "ß". But the strange behavior, the first time an error thrown, but the second time, the same line is already valid. I use xerces library.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 17; The entity "szlig" was referenced, but not declare
```

validation

```
    SchemaFactory factory = new XMLSchemaFactory();

try {
    InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(WTConstants.XSD_VALIDATOR);

    if (xmlString.startsWith("\uFEFF")) {
    xmlString = xmlString.substring(1);// remove BOM
    }

    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(stream));
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
} catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
    logger.error("Validation error: ", e);
    isXmlValid = false;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858914/entity-was-referenced-but-not-declared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858914/entity-was-referenced-but-not-declared)

Comment: I think no. It does not solve my problem ..

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the below code OR replace the ß character with the `&#223;` in your xml. This should work for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE definition [
<!ENTITY szlig "&#223;">
]>
```

**General Solution**

You can use a DOCTYPE declaration that refers to the [MathML DTD](http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml3/mathml3.dtd) or local copy of the same :

```
<!DOCTYPE math 
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD MathML 3.0//EN"
           "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml3/mathml3.dtd">
```

This DTD have all the entity references.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I fix this problem in general. The string to validate can be in different languages. This means that the validator will not work as soon as come some special character.

Comment: Have updated the answer, hope this will help you. within `mathml3.dtd`  you can see the `<!ENTITY % htmlmathmlent PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES HTML MathML Set//EN//XML" "htmlmathml-f.ent">` where [htmlmathml-f.ent](http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007/htmlmathml-f.ent) contains all the references.

Comment: Thanks. The file is quite large. At text validation, you should always insert this line. Can you please tell me how the validator understands, where is the local file "htmlmathml-f.ent"? I have Maven project.

Comment: Download DTD file from here [here](https://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/xhtml-math11-f-a.dtd) and update the path `http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml3/mathml3.dtd` to your local relative or absolute file path. if your all your files are in same directory you can just write `xhtml-math11-f-a.dtd` it will look into the same directory

Comment: Thank you! Understand. And is there any a shortened version of a file, so that was not all kinds of characters, but only those who really belong to the alphabets. I expect a good validation only by words. Plus 400 kb for each string validation, it is very much.And what will performens if validations will be hundreds?

Comment: You have the file now in your local machine, you can remove the unnecessary lines, and keep the lines whatever you feel important. and from the performance perspective it will not affect that much, as you can see developers uses tens of &nbsp; in code these all characters are replaced once.

Answer (score 0):

The only entities that are predeclared in XML are lt, gt, amp, quot, and apos. If you use any other entity name, you have to declare it.

This doesn't stop you using special characters. There are three ways you can use a non-ASCII character such as ß in XML:

(a) Just enter the character directly (making sure that the editor is configured to use the character encoding that matches the encoding declared in the XML declaration).

(b) Use a numeric character reference such as `&#223;`

(c) Use an entity reference such as `&eszet;`, making sure that the entity is declared in your DTD.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can not do that. Because the user himself will load a string, that will later validated and converted into XML.

Comment: I'm not sure which of the three you can't do (or why). You have to choose one of them, or abandon use of XML entirely.