# Regex to return a list of HTML special characters / code in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm building an XML file which will be used in WordPress / WP All Import, from a number of different sources and I'm bumping into a problem with undeclared entities.

What I'd like to do, is scan the file for potential entities, so I can add a list of entities to the file, similar to the answer provided here:
[Entity was referenced but not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858914/entity-was-referenced-but-not-declared)

The problem is I have no idea what regex to use to achieve this.

Here's an example of the XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<items>
    <item>
        <name>Example 1 &mdash; This is the first name</name>
        <description>This is a &quot;description&quot;</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Example 2 &ndash; This is the second name</name>
        <description>This is a &apos;description&apos;</description>
    </item>
</items>
```

I **suspect** I'd use something similar to the following, to drag out a list of matched entities:

```php
preg_match('[regex here]', file_get_contents($xml_file), $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

With the right regex, I was hoping to get a list of the HTML entities / codes used in the string provided:

```
&mdash;
&quot;
&ndash;
&apos;
```

...any insight or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :-)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/NTZjZv/1

Comment: That's the one, thanks zanderwar

Comment: Just wondered what you are going to do once you have this list.  Do you know the code you are going to attach to each one or are you just going to declare them with a dummy value to make the XML parse properly?

Comment: Going to start with a dummy value, Nigel (I suspect that's all that's needed); if that doesn't work, I'll have to find / put together a list.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to [zanderwar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2266583/zanderwar) for providing the regex. For those interested, here's the code I ended up implementing...

```
/**
 * Attempts to find any entities that require declaring in the
 * final XML file
 * 
 * @param string $string String to be checked / parsed
 * @param array $declarations List of entities already found
 * @return array Updated list of entities
 */
function getDeclarables($string = "", $declarations = [])
{
    preg_match('/\&\S+;?/', $string, $matches);
    if (is_array($matches) && count($matches)) 
    {
        foreach ($matches as $match) 
        {
            /** Don't need &amp; as it's already in the standard */
            if (($match != "&amp;") && !in_array($match, $declarations)) 
            {
                $declarations[] = $match;
            }
        }
    }
    return $declarations;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with `&[^;]+;`, because it won't need any backtracking.

Eplanation:

`&` - match `&` literally

`[^;]+` - negated character class: match one or more (due to `+` operator) of any character EXCEPT `;`

`;` - match `;` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM79p4/1)

Comment: This matches f.e. `&I'm not really an entity;` … You should at least exclude white space, I think.

Comment: @misorude I think it isn't necessary and might be desired by OP to match those as well.